# React state gets updated visually, but the state variable does not get updated when accessing through useContext

Tags: reactjs, jsx

There are a lot of different posts about state not updating, but I haven't found any that apply to my case.

In my `index.js` file, I have 2 `useState` hooks and all the components are wrapped inside the `<Context.Provider>` tag with the state values and setters as shown below:

```
                <Context.Provider
                    value={{
                        state1,
                        setState1,
                        state2,
                        setState2,
                    }}
                >
                    <OtherComponent1 />
                    <OtherComponent2 />
                </Context.Provider>
```

in another component, I've imported the values from the context like this:

```
    const {
        state1,
        setState2,
        state2,
        setState2,
    } = useContext(Context);
```

I can use both the state and the state setters perfectly, except when I set the state, I can see the visual changes, except the variable value doesn't change.

`state1` is an array, and when I do `setState1(updatedArray)`, I can see visually that the state is updated, but when I `console.log(state1)`, I still only see the original value of `state1`, not `updatedArray`. How can I fix this?

Also, when I do `useEffect(() => console.log(state1), [state1])`, I see the correct updated value of `state1`. This confuses me even more because this is the only place where I can see the correct value of `state1`, but I need the correct value elsewhere.

Comment: It means console.log is running in the previous iteration before states changed, that's why useEffect works, where exactly are you running console log?

Comment: @EdwynZN right after updating the state in the same function. However, the next time that function gets called, the value still is the same as the default `state1` value, which is weird.

Comment: Can you show where you do the console.log ?

Comment: Show the code of your function or component

Comment: Here's the function: `const insertTeamIntoRankings = (
  index: number,
  val: Team,
  currentTeamRankings: Team[]
 ) => {
  let rankings: Team[] = [...currentTeamRankings];
  rankings.splice(index, 0, val);
  setTeamRankings(rankings);
  console.log(teamRankings);
 };`

Comment: ew sorry that formatting is terrible, [here](https://pastebin.com/RFQELYZs), this should be more readable

Comment: Don't console log inside the function where you are setting the state. Try to have a console log in the component anywhere outside the render and see the value after the functoin is called

Answer (score 0):

as Ivo mentioned you should use console log outside the function to check for the state of teamRankings. The function holds the previous data and by extension console log prints the previous state. Thats why useEffect works, because it checks that the state changed and re runs the effect

Comment: That's what I assumed, however, the next time I call the function, the value is still the same as before. [Here's the function](https://pastebin.com/RFQELYZs). The second time the function gets called, `teamRankings` is still blank, even though a value should have been added the first time it was called.

Comment: try using useCallback and pass setTeamRankings and teamRankings to the dependency array